# jquery noConflict issue

Tags: lightbox, jquery

I am trying to use [Lightbox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/#how) plugin but with jquery there is a conflict and gone through some articles and find out to get work around this but I have no luck in implementing it.

Here is my code:
References:

```
<link href="Lightbox/css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="Lightbox/js/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Lightbox/js/scriptaculous.js?load=effects,builder">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Lightbox/js/lightbox.js"></script>
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    (function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("a[rel=lightbox[group1]]").live("click", function () {
                $("a[rel^='lightbox[group1]']").lightbox();
                return false;
            });
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

I am using jquery 1.5.2 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent `$` conflicts between jQuery and prototype, you have to put `jQuery.noConflict();` right after you include jQuery and before any other code that expects `$` to belong to another library. Then, once you've done that, `$` will not map to jQuery, it will be used by the other libraries.

You don't show how you include jQuery.  Here's an example right from the [jQuery doc page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) for `.noConflcit()`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
  });
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

In your case, I think your code would go like this:

```
<link href="Lightbox/css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="Lightbox/js/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Lightbox/js/scriptaculous.js?load=effects,builder">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Lightbox/js/lightbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    (function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("a[rel=lightbox[group1]]").live("click", function () {
                $("a[rel^='lightbox[group1]']").lightbox();
                return false;
            });
        });
        // other jQuery code that uses $ can go here
    })(jQuery);
    // other jQuery code that uses jQuery (but not $) can go here or in other script tags
</script>
```

The order of including js files in relation to the call to `jQuery.noConflict()` is critically important.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks right, so I'm thinking jQuery isn't loaded?
If using `jQuery` instead of `$` doesn't work, then that's probably the case.

If you have the jQuery script in your site header, you'll want check FireBug's net console to see if it loaded - Google Chrome also has a nice network monitor you can use.

You could also use a [jQuery lightbox](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/) instead of introducing the prototype library just to use a single plugin.

Comment: @Francis-I have changed '$' to 'jquery' but then also it did not work.

Comment: is jQuery loaded? From the list of scripts you show as loaded, jQuery isn't listed.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using jQuery object instead of $:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("a[rel=lightbox[group1]]").live("click", function () {
            jQuery("a[rel^='lightbox[group1]']").lightbox();
            return false;
            });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @DotNetter What happens? Do you get a js error? Can you add it to your question?

Comment: @Arnold-I'm not getting any error as I need to display dyanmically uploaded images using plupload uploader which I mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994310/whats-wrong-with-this-jquery-live-method